# Sesame won't open Turtle file created by Jena

Tags: jena, sesame, turtle-rdf

A [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) file created by Jena is not opening in Sesame. On a closer analysis, I found that Jena uses namespace prefixes but Sesame uses the compete namespace. How can I resolve this?

This is what Sesame uses:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0_2c> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.key> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.it_title.Alexanderplatz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.ar.apjvik0623apjvik0644apjvik0643apjvik0633apjvik0627apjvik0646apjvik062Fapjvik0631_apjvik0628apjvik0644apjvik0627apjvik062Aapjvik0632> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.ar_title.apjvik0645apjvik064Aapjvik062Fapjvik0627apjvik0646_apjvik0623apjvik0644apjvik0643apjvik0633apjvik0646apjvik062Fapjvik0631> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.pl_title.Alexanderplatz> ;
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/location.location> ;
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.key> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.nl_id.429277> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.ca.Alexanderplatz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.en_id.2511> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.nl_title.Alexanderplatz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.fr_id.749899> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.fa.apjvik0627apjvik0644apjvik0643apjvik0633apjvik0627apjvik0646apjvik062Fapjvik0631apjvik067Eapjvik0644apjvik0627apjvik062Aapjvik0633> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.ru.apjvik0410apjvik043Bapjvik0435apjvik043Aapjvik0441apjvik0430apjvik043Dapjvik0434apjvik0435apjvik0440apjvik043Fapjvik043Bapjvik0430apjvik0446> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.zh-tw.apjvik4E9Aapjvik5386apjvik5C71apjvik5927apjvik5E7Fapjvik573A> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.th_title.apjvik0E2Dapjvik0E40apjvik0E25apjvik0E47apjvik0E01apjvik0E0Bapjvik0E32apjvik0E19apjvik0E40apjvik0E14apjvik0E2Dapjvik0E23apjvik0E4Capjvik0E1Eapjvik0E25apjvik0E32apjvik0E17apjvik0E0Bapjvik0E4C> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.it.Haus_des_Reisens> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.fr.Alexanderplatz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.en.Alexander_Platz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/wikipedia.cs_title.Alexanderplatz> , <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/user.avh.ellerdale.0099-a6ea> ;
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic> ;
```

This is what Jena uses:

```
@prefix key: <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/>.
@prefix ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>. 
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

ns:m.0_2c
ns:common.topic.alias    "Alexanderplatz, Berlin"@en;
```

Comment: What error do you get? What versions of Jena and of Sesame are you using?

Comment: There's a very simple serialization called [N-Triples](http://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/) where there is one triple per line, and there are no prefixes.  Your triple would look like:  `<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0_2c> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias> "Alexanderplatz, Berlin"@en .`.  Despite the similarity in names, N3 is quite different from N-Triples.  N3 and Turtle are very similar, though (in fact, Turtle is a subset of N3).  Are you sure you're using Sesame's Turtle/N3 loader and not its N-Triples loader?

Comment: As Andy said, what error message are you getting?  Can you show a minimal example of this?  I.e., please show a _complete_ file created by Jena that Sesame won't open, and the error output that you get from Sesame. The meaning of the error output will probably make the problem very clear to some of the people here with more knowledge of Sesame.

Comment: I am using seasame 2.7.7 the latest release that came around 15 days back. Same with jena, I picked up the latest jar. I have already given the snippet of jena file. I will paste the snippet from the seasame file.

Comment: I tried pasting the snippet from seasame , but the character limit here is too small, to give any meaningful sample. The best way to explain the difference is that in the jena example you see ns:, but in case of seasame ns: is replaced by complete uri.

Comment: I was able to modify my original post. please look into it for the seasame sample

Comment: It's still not clear what the actual problem is. You have a Turtle file produced by Jena, and try to load it into Sesame. Since you show the result of the load operation in Sesame (the data without prefixes), it's clear that Sesame actually _does_ load the file. If your actual question is why you don't see the namespace prefixes in the Sesame result, you'll have to give us details about *how* you get that result out of Sesame, and also how you load the data.

Comment: Let me explain what i did. a)created a turtle file using jena and tried to load it into seasame , It failed to load in seasame . b)I created an rdf file from jena and was able to successfully load it into seasame. c) to debug the issue why the turtle file could not be loaded, I created a turtle file using seasame. The resultant file is uploaded above. d) looking at the turtle files I see the issue is due to the difference in the namespace handling in both seasame and jena

Answer (score 1):

I had a closer look: the cause is actually that the Turtle file produced by Jena contains a '.' in the localname part of a prefixed name (the `m.02_c` bit, and the `common.topic.alias` bit). This is allowed by the current W3C REC Turtle grammar, but Sesame does not yet fully implement this version of Turtle. This is a known issue ([SES-1862](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-1862)).

Sesame is scheduled to be brought up to date with the latest Turtle spec for its next major release, 2.8. In the meantime, a workaround is to use a different syntax format when exporting from Jena (e.g. N-Triples).